# AttributeError: 'StringIndexer' object has no attribute

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am building a decision tree in Pyspark. So Have used StringIndexer to convert the string attribute to numeric for further computation

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="SKL", outputCol="IndexedLabel")
```

Later on when I am using IndexTo String to revert back the column into String format as below

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import IndexToString
PredConverter = IndexToString(inputCol='prediction', outputCol='predictionStr',labels=indexer.SKL)
predictions = PredConverter.transform(dtc_preds)
predictions.show()
```

I am getting error as : **AttributeError: 'StringIndexer' object has no attribute 'SKL'**

Although when I am checking the input column names in the StringIndexer class object as below, it is printing as SKL as output

```
print(indexer.getInputCol())
```

**This is my full code**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer,IndexToString
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('tree').getOrCreate()  
userKnowDf=spark.read.csv('/FileStore/tables/UserKnowModelingDataset_Train.csv',inferSchema=True, header=True)
userKnowDf.describe().show()
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="SKL", outputCol="IndexedLabel")
indexedUserKnow = indexer.fit(userKnowDf).transform(userKnowDf)

df= indexedUserKnow.selectExpr(("IndexedLabel"),("SKL as label"),("SST"),("SRT"),("SAT"),("SAP"),("SEP"));

assembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=['SST','SRT','SAT','SAP','SEP'],outputCol='features')

LRdf = assembler.transform(df).select('IndexedLabel','label','features')

split=LRdf.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])

trainingdata=split[0]
testdata=split[1]

dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol='IndexedLabel', featuresCol='features')
dtc_model=dtc.fit(trainingdata)
dtc_preds = dtc_model.transform(testdata)

dtc_preds.show()

PredConverter = IndexToString(inputCol='prediction', outputCol='predictionStr',labels=indexer.SKL) // Getting error here
predictions = PredConverter.transform(dtc_preds)
predictions.show()
```

Comment: Try to use `from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, IndexToString` **or** `from pyspark.ml.feature import *`

Comment: Have tried with that but got same error

Comment: In "PredConverter = ... ", change `labels=indexer.SKL` to `labels=indexer.labels`.

Comment: Received below error
AttributeError: 'StringIndexer' object has no attribute 'labels'

Comment: you need StringIndexerModel object which is missing from your routine, add `indexer_model = indexer.fit(userKnowDf)`, and then use `labels=indexer_model.labels`

Comment: I wrote as below
StringIndexerModel indexer = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("SKL").setOutputoCl("indexedLabel")

Then it is showing as invalid syntax.

I also import the packages as below
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer,IndexToString,StringIndexerModel